# The name "ClassicBorderDecorator" does not exist in the namespace "clr-namespace:Microsoft.Windows.Themes;assembly=PresentationFramework.Aero"

Tags: .net, wpf, xaml, border, aero

I have been charged with fixing somebody elses work, but this error is puzzling me.

```
The name "ClassicBorderDecorator" does not exist in the namespace "clr-namespace:Microsoft.Windows.Themes;assembly=PresentationFramework.Aero"
```

I have a reference set to PresentaionFramework.Aero already included and the xmlns tag set, what am I missing?

```
<Application
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
    xmlns:Microsoft_Windows_Themes="clr-namespace:Microsoft.Windows.Themes;assembly=PresentationFramework.Aero" x:Class="Application"
    StartupUri="MainWindow.xaml">
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have not tried it but it seems that that `ClassicBorderDecorator` is defined in `PresentationFramework.Classic.dll` (not in `PresentationFramework.Aero.dll`). So you need to fix your reference and change your namespace definition:

```
 <Application
      xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
      xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
      xmlns:Microsoft_Windows_Themes="clr-namespace:Microsoft.Windows.Themes;assembly=PresentationFramework.Classic"     
      x:Class="Application" StartupUri="MainWindow.xaml">
```